# What is a more efficient / tidier way of breaking this string down?

Tags: c#, string, optimization

I'm trying to break down this string into 2 colours and wondered if there is a neater way of achieving the same result?

```
// Obtain colour values
string cssConfig = "primary-colour:Red, secondary-colour:Blue";
var parts = cssConfig.Split(',');
var colour1 = parts[0].Split(':')[1];
var colour2 = parts[1].Split(':')[1];
```

Comment: What do you mean by efficient? Less code? Less processor time? Less development effort?

Comment: All of the above. Not so worried about development time though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use regex

```
string cssConfig = "primary-colour:Red, secondary-colour:Blue";
var reg = new Regex(@"([\w\-]+)\:([\w\-]+)");
foreach (Match match in reg.Matches(cssConfig))
{

}
```

Also you could do something with LINQ

```
    var cssConfigDict = cssConfig.Split(',')
                        .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.FirstOrDefault(), y => y.LastOrDefault());
```

There is probably a better way with LINQ!

Comment: hmmm two upvotes but no one _read_ the regex, at least not with regards to css/style attribute syntax

Comment: The question doesn't specifically say it is CSS it may just be a string that will become CSS

Comment: Your right it's not css just a string that is stored in the database (was formed in that way already)

Comment: But @sehe does make a fair point, the regex I listed has only been tested against the string you supplied

Answer (score 3):

A Regex is definitely a possibility, though whether it's "neater" or more readable depends on personal preference and your ability to read regular expressions. If the actual use case of this is really just reading those *two* colors and not an arbitrary amount of colors then I'd probably just stay with the original solution. The intent is quite clear while keeping the code simple and avoids subtle errors if Regexes aren't your strong point.

LINQ is probably the most readable variant and would easily allow reading multiple key-value pairs while still using simple splitting mechanism to parse the data.

From my experience what you should definitely avoid for the sake of maintainability is writing a hugely complex, generic and seemingly "neat" solution for a problem this small and simple.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the LINQ methods:

```
var colors = cssConfig.Split(',').Select(x => x.Split(':').Skip(1).Take(1));
```

Having said that, I would stick with your method. It is clear code that everyone understands. The regex version and the LINQ version is more obscure...

Answer (score 1):

Check this its similar to your requirement , to get the dictionary object form the string

[Regex To Linq to Dictionary in C#](http://omegacoder.com/?p=245)

```
string input = "abc:1|bbbb:2|xyz:45|p:120";
string pattern = @"(?<Key>[^:]+)(?:\:)(?<Value>[^|]+)(?:\|?)";

Dictionary<string, string> KVPs
    = ( from Match m in Regex.Matches( input, pattern )
      select new
      {
          key = m.Groups["Key"].Value,
          value = m.Groups["Value"].Value
       }
       ).ToDictionary( p => p.key, p => p.value );

foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in KVPs )
    Console.WriteLine( "{0,6} : {1,3}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value );

/* Outputs:
 abc :   1
bbbb :   2
 xyz :  45
  p  : 120
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the order will always be the same. Which you'd need for your solution to work anyways, you could do:

```
// Obtain colour values
string cssConfig = "primary-colour:Red, secondary-colour:Blue";
var parts = cssConfig.Split(',',':');
var colour1 = parts[1];
var colour2 = parts[3];
```